# How to assign index while ignoring NAs by group

Tags: r, data.table, na

given the following `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4), Year1=c(NA, 30, 40, NA), Year2=c(NA, 30, 20 ,70), Year3=c(60, 40, 0, 10), Year4=c(10,20,30,30)) 
dtm <- melt(dt, id.var = 'id')[order(id, variable)]
```

I would like to assign index to `dtm`, so that the expected return will be as follows:

```
   id variable value index
 1:  1    Year1    NA    NA
 2:  1    Year2    NA    NA
 3:  1    Year3    60     1
 4:  1    Year4    10     2
 5:  2    Year1    30     1
 6:  2    Year2    30     2
 7:  2    Year3    40     3
 8:  2    Year4    20     4
 9:  3    Year1    40     1
10:  3    Year2    20     2
11:  3    Year3     0     3
12:  3    Year4    30     4
13:  4    Year1    NA    NA
14:  4    Year2    70     1
15:  4    Year3    10     2
16:  4    Year4    30     3
```

I have tried `dtm[ ,index:=1:.N, by = id]`, but it does not ignore NAs.

Could you please give me suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to specify the 'i' to ignore the NAs

```
dtm[!is.na(value), index := 1:.N , by = id]
dtm
#    id variable value index
# 1:  1    Year1    NA    NA
# 2:  1    Year2    NA    NA
# 3:  1    Year3    60     1
# 4:  1    Year4    10     2
# 5:  2    Year1    30     1
# 6:  2    Year2    30     2
# 7:  2    Year3    40     3
# 8:  2    Year4    20     4
# 9:  3    Year1    40     1
#10:  3    Year2    20     2
#11:  3    Year3     0     3
#12:  3    Year4    30     4
#13:  4    Year1    NA    NA
#14:  4    Year2    70     1
#15:  4    Year3    10     2
#16:  4    Year4    30     3
```

Or if we are using the devel version (comments from @Frank)

```
dtm[!is.na(value), z := rowid(id)]
```

Comment: Or, in version 1.9.7 or later: `dtm[!is.na(value), z := rowid(id)]`

Comment: @akrun I have tried to start the index from 0, which is replaced `index:=1:.N` by `index:=0:.N`, it returns the following warnings 

`Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(dtm, !is.na(value), `:=`(index, 0:.N), by = id) :
  RHS 1 is length 3 (greater than the size (2) of group 1). The last 1 element(s) will be discarded.`

So, I use `dtm[!is.na(value, index:=(1L:.N)-1L, by = id]`, instead and it works fine.  I am not sure what create the warning message.

Comment: @newbie I am not getting any warning with your example